# Android - Explanation of sensor

Tags: android, sensors

I am working with sensors, and I found this code on a website. I understand most of the code, but I don't understand the calculation with float speed = Math.abs.. Can someone explain that please? Furthermore i am a little bit confused about the last_x, last_y, and last_z.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SensorEventListener {

//ACCELEROMETER
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private SensorEventListener mSensorListener = this;
private long lastUpdate = 0;
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
private static final int shakeSensitivity = 600;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    float x = e.values[0];
    float y = e.values[1];
    float z = e.values[2];

    //Find current time
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //Check if more than 100 milliseconds (0,1 sec) has passed since last invokment of this onSensorChanged method
    if ((currentTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
        long diffTime = (currentTime - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = currentTime;

        float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;

        if (speed > shakeSensitivity) {
           //do something
        }

        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;
    }

}
```

Comment: Math.abs returns the absolute value of a value. If it is -7 it will return 7.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value You can't really have negative speed so that's why it's calculated that way.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But do you understand the last part, when dividing with diffTime and multiplying with 10000? Why 10000?